# Visual Basic 2012: Passing variable from one form to another

Tags: vb.net, showdialog

I have two forms, the main (Main.vb) program window and a pop-up that appears when the program is started (getInitialBalance.vb). I need to get a value entered into the PopUp window from the popup window to the Main program. The relevant code is shown below:

### getinitialbalance.vb

```
Public Class GetInitialBalance
    Public initialBalance As Integer

    Private Sub btnApplyInitialBal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnApplyInitialBal.Click
        Dim textinput As Integer = txtInitialBalance.Text
        initialBalance = textinput
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

### Main.vb

```
Public Class Main
    Private Sub Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        GetInitialBalance.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Dim localInitialBalance As Integer = GetInitialBalance.initialBalance

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MsgBox(localInitialBalance)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New up the `GetInitialBalance` form and then when the user clicks `OK` on the popup dialog, grab the value `initialBalance` from the reference to `GetInitialBalance`, like this:

```
Private Sub Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim popup As New GetInitialBalance
    If popup.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        localInitialBalance = popup.initialBalance
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Your entire code should look like this:

```
Public Class GetInitialBalance
    Public initialBalance As Integer

    Private Sub btnApplyInitialBal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnApplyInitialBal.Click
        initialBalance = Convert.ToInt32(textinput)
        Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Main
    Dim localInitialBalance As Integer

    Private Sub Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim popup As New GetInitialBalance
        If popup.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            localInitialBalance = popup.initialBalance
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MsgBox(localInitialBalance)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Change `Me.Close()` to `Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK`.

Comment: Hehe...pretty sure he just means to create an instance of GetInitialBalance() using the `new` keyword (2nd line of first snippet), as opposed to displaying the "default instance" as you were doing originally.

Comment: Yeah, I got it. It threw a compiler error when I tried it the first time, but I changed it based on your first comment and now everything is good.

Comment: @Idle_Mind - ah thanks, I will update the answer. Copy and paste and typing too fast got me again. :-)

Comment: @tjtoml - thanks for making the edit, approved and I am glad this helped you out. Feel free to up-vote the answer when you can. :-)

Comment: @KarlAnderson You approving my edit (or upvoting my question) got me to 15, score. Thanks for your help, I'll probably be back trying to finish this exam tonight...