# ToolStripTextBox action on pressing Enter key

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I've got a similar issue - i've created a Windows Form Application which basically looks up data from a SQL server based on a code entered into the ToolStripTextBox. This works great when the button is clicked however I'd like to add the function of hitting enter after typing and that brings the results through.

```
Public Class Form1
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DataSet.Table' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.TableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet.Table)
  End Sub

  Private Sub FillBySearchToolStripButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FillBySearchToolStripButton.Click
    Try
        Me.TableTableAdapter.FillBySearch(Me.DataSet.Table, TYPEToolStripTextBox.Text)
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
  End Sub
End Class
```

Appologies as  I am a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the KeyDown event:

```
Private Sub ToolStripTextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) _
                                      Handles ToolStripTextBox1.KeyDown
  If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
    'run your code
  End If
End Sub
```

The "run your code" block could just call the click event:

```
FillBySearchToolStripButton.PerformClick()
```

Comment: Thanks Larstech, I did manage to figure this one out eventually ha!  Could you answer another?

I'd like to pass a variable from one form to another, ask for another variable on that form then on the final form show all entered variables - would you know where to go to find out how to do this?

Comment: @NewbieVB If a post answers your question, feel free to click on the check mark next to it to accept it.  As far as the new question, that gets asked almost every day, usually with downvotes to the poster because it's been asked so many times.  It googles easy.  Here is an example: [Visual Basic 2012: Passing variable from one form to another](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20111894/719186)